# asp.net mvc 5 - ajax upload , 500 (Internal Server Error)

Tags: asp.net, ajax, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

I have a problem with ajax post request, it gives **500 (Internal Server Error)**. During development, I do not have this problem but when I deploy on server this 500 (Internal Server Error) appears.

controller

```
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public JsonResult RMAImageUpload(myModel model)
{
    int imageId = 0;

    var file = model.ImageFile;

    if (file != null)
    {

        file.SaveAs(Server.MapPath("/path/" + file.FileName));

    }

    return Json(imageId, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);

}
```

View

```
var formData = new FormData();
formData.append('__RequestVerificationToken', $("[name='__RequestVerificationToken']").val());
formData.append('ImageFile', file[0]);
formData.append('RMAId', $("[id='RMAId']").val());

$.ajax({
    type: "Post",
    url: "@Url.Action("RMAImageUpload", "ImageStores")",
    data: formData,
    datatype: "json",
    processData: false,
    contentType: false,
    success: function(response) {
        ClearPreview();
        $("#uploadedImage")
            .append('<img src="/UploadedImage/' + response + '" class="img-responsive thumbnail"/>');
    }
});
```

I do not know why this problem will appear when I deploy on server.

my Server ... shared windows host

Comment: check your server logs and find the underlying error, this will give you a better clue. A 500 error is just a generic message to cover up the real error (usually for security reasons). I would guess there is some difference in your server setup and your local setup. Just a guess, based on your code, perhaps you don't have permission to save to the folder, or it doesn't exist or something. Finding the real error message will tell you what's going on.

Comment: Also a side note, why are you specifying `JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet` when the action method is decorated with `[HttpPost]` to prevent GET requests? Doesn't make much sense.

Comment: You may need to check full error message on the server as 500 internal server error is generic issue.